# Can I use LIVE ID to insert a reminder into the Windows 8 Calendar?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-live-id

I am developing a Windows 8 Store App using c# & XAML.

I would like to use the Live ID SDK to connect to the calendar in order to schedule reminders there.

Is this route possible, and is it the right way to do it from Windows 8 Store App? and if so which would be a good sample to follow here?

Thanks
EitanB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Live SDK to create events in users calendar provided they sign in with their live ID and approve it. You can find more details and sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826523.aspx